# Set Vagrant VM name to be current working directory

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'd like to set the name of my Vagrant VM to be the current working directory. I'd like to do something like this but apparently it's not valid:

`config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name = ENV[$PWD]
  end`

Suggestions are much appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The following will work

```
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      current_dir = File.basename(Dir.getwd)
      vb.name = current_dir
  end
```